# Install sparklyr with initialize_connect error

Tags: rstudio, sparklyr

I'm trying to follow the simple guide on SparklyR, but it throws me errors right at the very beginning. I install SparklyR and a local version of Spark as written in the guide:

`library("sparklyr")`

`spark_install(version="1.6.2")`

I then open a connection, and here's where the error occurs:

`sc <- spark_connect(master="local")`

I get "R code execution error" and the following:

Using Spark: 2.2.0
Error in force(code) : 
  Failed during initialize_connection: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the author of `Sparklyr` answered my question. Since I have both Java 8 and Java 9 installed, which `Sparklyr` is currently not working with Java 9. so I simply uninstall Java 9, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

"1.6.2" is way old.

Does this work?

```
spark_install(version="2.2.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master="local", version="2.2.0)
```

Comment: I know it is old, I was trying to follow a tutorial. Actually I have tried 2.2.0, it still give me the same error